# Android Room: Is there a way to return a variable of when the queries are successful or empty?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

Is there a way to return when a query has been successful such as inserting, updating and returning empty queries (ie: when you get something from the database and the database is empty)?

*Edit
The reason I asked is because I want to turn off the spinner but the observer function never gets called because the database is empty.

The flow is, the View calls the `getAll()` function and retrieves a list from the database, from there, the items in the list get sent to an API and returns objects into a list of `LiveData`

DAO

```
@Dao
interface Dao {

    @Insert
    suspend fun insert(object: Object)

    @Update
    suspend fun update(object: Object)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(object: Object)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM table")
    suspend fun getAll(): List<String>

    @Query("DELETE FROM table")
    suspend fun deleteAll()
}
```

Repo

```
    fun getObject(list: List<String>): LiveData<ArrayList<Object>> {
        val tempList: ArrayList<Object> = ArrayList()
        if (list.isEmpty())
            return MutableLiveData()

        list.forEach {item ->
            objects = jsonApi.getObject(item, API_KEY)
            objects.enqueue(object : Callback<Object> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<Object>?, t: Throwable?) {
                    Log.d("Error", "Code: " + t.toString())
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call<Object>?, response: Response<Object>?) {
                    if (response!!.isSuccessful) {
                        tempList.add(response.body()!!)
                        liveDataList.value = tempList
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        return liveDataList
    }

suspend fun getAll(): List<String> {
        return dao.getAll()
    }
```

ViewModel

```
private fun getObject(list: List<String>): LiveData<ArrayList<Object>> {
        return repo.getObject(list)
    }

fun getAll(): LiveData<ArrayList<Object>> = runBlocking {
        return@runBlocking getObject(repo.getAll())
    }
```

View

```
mainActivityViewModel.getAll().observe(this, Observer {list ->
            adapter.setList(list)
            recyclerView.adapter = adapter
            progressSpinner.visibility = View.GONE
        })
```

Comment: Please limit yourself to a single question per post on Stack Overflow, or it is at risk of being closed as off-topic.

Comment: My apologies, I just thought the questions were similar enough. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Can you include your Room Dao with your query and what type of LiveData you return? Room would return an empty list when you have an empty database when you return a `LiveData<List<YourItem>>`

Comment: @ianhanniballake yes, I added it there!

Comment: Your Dao doesn't have any `LiveData` objects at all? How do the code snippets you've included link together?

Comment: Sorry, added the rest of the code. The flow is, the View calls the ```getAll()``` function and retrieves a list from the database, from there, the items in the list get sent to an API and returns objects into a list of ```LiveData```. Will add this description into the question.